# How to emit event to app root in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement toast message (notification) on my React Native app.
I'm Thinking about implement my Toast component inside app root, and when a button is clicked (somewhere in the app), the app root will know about it and make the toast visible.
I don't want to use a library because I have complicated UI for this and I want to include buttons inside the toast.

This is the root component - `App.js`:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import {Toast} from './src/components/Toast';
import store from './src/store/Store.js';
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator';
import StatusBar from './src/components/StatusBar';

export default function App(props) {
    return (
        <Provider store = { store }>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>
            <AppNavigator />
            <Toast></Toast>
          </View>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

EDIT:

`AppNavigator.js`:

```
// this is how I connect each page:
let HomePage = connect(state => mapStateToProps, dispatch => mapDispatchToProps(dispatch))(HomeScreen);
let SearchPage = connect(state => mapStateToProps, dispatch => mapDispatchToProps(dispatch))(SearchScreen);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomePage,
        Search: SearchPage,
    },
    config
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        // State
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        // Actions
    }
};

export default tabNavigator;
```

Any ideas how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, i would suggest to use a component to wrap your application where you have your toast. For example:

App.js

```
render(){
    return (
      <Provider store = { store }>
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <AppContainer/>
          </View>
    </Provider>
    )
}
```

Where your `AppContainer` would have a render method similar to this:

```
render(){
    return (
        <Frament>
            <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>
            <AppNavigator />
            <Toast></Toast>
        </Fragment>
        )
}
```

Then (as you are using redux) you can connect your `AppContainer`. After that, just make this component aware of changes on redux using `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if(this.props.redux_toast.visible !== prevProps.redux_toast.visible){
        this.setState({
            toastVisible : this.props.redux_toast.visible,
            toastMessage: this.props.redux_toast.message
        })
    }
}
```

This is just an example on how it could be done by using redux, I don't know how your toast or redux structure is, but it should be an available solution for your use case.

EDIT.

This is how it should look like:

```
//CORE
import React from 'react';

//REDUX
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store/store';
import AppContainer from './AppContainer';


export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

AppContainer.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Stylesheet } from "react-native";
import StatusBar from "path/to/StatusBar";
import AppNavigator from "path/to/AppNavigator";
import Toast from "path/to/Toast";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


class AppContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            toastVisible:false,
            toastMessage:""
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
        if(this.props.redux_toast.visible !== prevProps.redux_toast.visible){
            this.setState({
                toastVisible : this.props.redux_toast.visible,
                toastMessage: this.props.redux_toast.message
            })
        }
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>
                <AppNavigator />
                <Toast visible={this.state.toastVisible}
                    message={this.state.toastMessage}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1
    }
})

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ ...yourMapStateToProp })

const mapDispatchToProps = state => ({ ...mapDispatchToProps })

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer)
```

Rest of the code remains untouched, you need to dispatch an action that changes a props that your appContainer's `componentDidUpdate` is listening to (in the example i called it `redux_toast.visible`).

Comment: Sounds like the perfect solution for me. The only problem is that the `AppNavigator` can't get any props (so I can't connect it). I edited my question so you can see what I am talking about. It's not the whole code of `AppNavigator`, but you can get the idea. THANK YOU!

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem, just export the AppContainer.js (new file) connecting it. Like `export default connect(AppContainer)`, `AppNavigator` (and rest of the app) will be left untouched. It's a rework of `App.js` splitting it into 2 files

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. Could you please show me an example or be specific? How do I connect each page on `AppNavigator`? Thanks!!

Comment: That part of code will not be touched, you should work outside the AppNavigator. You need to create a new component that wraps around the appContainer. I'll write a little sample about it

Comment: AMAZING! Totally clear now. So i'll have two `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` (inside AppContainer and AppNavigator), right?

Comment: Yes, based of your needs!